# How can I change the value of an object in react based on form data input by the user?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, react-redux

I am using react and trying to build a payment system using the paypal button v2 and need to let users input how much money they want to charge themselves.  Currently the code that would handle this looks like:

```
export const Payment = () => {

let product = {
    price: 123,
    description: "Dues total payment: "
  };


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="landing-inner">
        {paidFor ? (
          <div>
            <h1>You have successfully paid your dues</h1>
          </div>
        ) : (
            <div>
              <h1 className="x-large text-primary">
                {product.description} ${product.price}
              </h1>
              <div ref={v => (paypalRef = v)} />
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Payment;
```

product.price is the value I need to be able to allow users to alter, but it needs to remain a number so the code handling the payment understands it.

I am pretty brand new to react and have been racking my brain trying to figure out how to get this content to act dynamically but I am struggling to get this working, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using hooks like useState and useRef:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useRef } from "react";

export const Payment = () => {

  const [price, setPrice] = useState(123);
  const [paidFor] = useState(false);
  const priceRef = useRef(null);

  let product = {
    price,
    description: "Dues total payment: "
  };

  const onHandlePay = () => {
    setPrice(priceRef.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="landing-inner">
        {paidFor ? (
          <div>
            <h1>You have successfully paid your dues</h1>
          </div>
        ) : (
            <div>
              <h1 className="x-large text-primary">
                {product.description} ${product.price}
              </h1>
              <div>
                 <input type="text" ref={priceRef} />
                 <button onClick={onHandlePay} type="button">
                   Pay
                 </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Payment;
```

check out this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-driscoll-odqmo